# bash order-of-operations in math context: Wrong value assigned

Tags: linux, shell

Given the linux shell code,

```
~$ (( b = a, (a += 3) + $((a = 1)), b++ ))
~$ echo $b
2
```

Why does `$b` equal 2? I split the code into three steps:

```
~$ ((b = a))
~$ (((a += 3) + $((a = 1))))
~$ ((b++))
~$ echo $b
1
```

`$b` equals 1 this time, why?

---

P.S. Neither a nor b is initialized.

Comment: I'm struggling to parse the original line but assuming that `a` isn't initialised, when you split the code up into 3 steps (which aren't equivalent to the original line), the value of `b` is `0` (from the first step) incremented by `1` (from the last step).

Comment: @TomFenech neither a nor b is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set `b = a`, then bash waits for **last** assigning of `a`. In `b` will be assigned same value as the value assigned to `a`.

```
~$ (( b = a, (a += 3) + $((a = 5)), b++ ))
~$ echo $b
6
~$ echo $a
8
```

**EDIT**

1) column-separated expressions are treated sequentially

```
~$ echo $((1+1, 2+2, 3+3))
6
```

2) `$((...))` expressions are treated first

*which gives result:*

```
(( b = a, (a += 3) + $((a = 1)), b++ ))
```

1. `$((a = 1)) #a=1`
2. `b = a      #a=b=1`
3. `a += 3     #a=4, b=1`
4. `b++        #a=4, b=2`

Comment: in the first step b=a, then it changes a=5, b=5 and afterwards b++ which means b=6

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the order of evaluation?

Comment: It looks like your reasoning is correct but it's not clear why the assignment is delayed. Do you know what the rule is, or have any evidence to show that this is what is happening?

Comment: Only in GNU manual I have found something about this topic: 
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html

Comment: It would be great if you could expand your answer to include some quotes from the relevant sections of those pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87803/discussion-between-andrew-and-tom-fenech).

Comment: This isn't *quite* correct, since `bash` isn't waiting for anything. Rather, the embedded `$((...))` is evaluated before the enclosing `((...))` is.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are not equivalent. The arithmetic expansion `$((...))` is performed before the `(( ... ))` statement is evaluated, so the following are equivalent:

```
(( b = a, (a += 3) + $((a = 1)), b++ ))
```

and

```
a=1
(( b = a, (a += 3) + a, b++ ))
```

Your attempt at breaking it into three parts is equivalent to

```
((b = a))  # b = 0 since uninitialized a is treated as 0
a=1
(((a += 3) + a))
((b++))    # b = 1
```

The difference is when, in the sequence of evaluation, `a` is first assigned the value of 1.